# How to reference an asset in class library in UWP with XAML syntax

Tags: c#, uwp, assets, uwp-xaml, class-library

I have a class library with a custom control in UWP. There is an asset **image.png** that is in the class library under the folder **Assets**

I want to display this image in the custom control using xaml syntax in generic.xaml inside the class library.

Answer (score 12):

That took me quite a while to solve, so I am posting the outcome for future explorers of the topic since I didn't manage to find a good solution anywhere.

Location of the files is:
**ClassLibraryName/Assets/image.scale-100.png
ClassLibraryName/Assets/image.scale-150.png**
etc.

Build action: **Content**
Copy to Output Directory: **Do not Copy**

In generic.xaml I have this now and the image loads correctly:
    Image Source="../ClassLibraryName/Assets/image.png"

It also works like this:
    Image Source="ms-appx:///ClassLibraryName/Assets/image.png"